# Unable to use 'x' and '+' markers in Seaborn stripplot

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I am trying to use seaborn.stripplot() to do categorical plots as shown below  using the reproducible code:

```
import seaborn as sns

df = sns.load_dataset('iris')

sns.stripplot(data = df,
              x="species", y="sepal_length", 
              color = 'red',jitter=False,zorder=3, marker='X')
```

[image]

But when I use `'x'` or `'+'` or `'_'` and other non-filled markers as a marker it is returning nothing, why so?

Comment: try lowercase 'x'

Comment: I tried. But it is not working.

Comment: Seems like something to do with line widths perhaps: other markers that fail include `"1"` through `"4"`, for example, from [here](https://matplotlib.org/api/markers_api.html#module-matplotlib.markers).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`stripplot()` is weird with non-filled markers. There is something going on with the linewidths of the markers. You can get them to appear if you pass `linewidth=1`, but note that if you use `linewidths` with an "s", that does not work.

```
sns.stripplot(data = df,
              x="species", y="sepal_length", 
              color='red', jitter=False, marker='x', linewidth=1)
```

[image]

Comment: There is an [open issue on seaborn's github](https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn/issues/2159) about this. It seems to be a new problem that's being worked on. @BigBen